# Getting most recent record for each row where a condition based on another column holds (Hive SQL)

Tags: hive, hiveql

Apologies if this is a repeat question, but I haven't been able to find something that answers my question directly. I have a table that looks like:

```
Person | Date       | In-office 
-------------------------------
1      | 01-01-2021 | 0
1      | 01-02-2021 | 1
1      | 01-04-2021 | 0
1      | 01-08-2021 | 1
2      | 01-02-2021 | 1
2      | 01-05-2021 | 0
2      | 01-09-2021 | 0
3      | 01-01-2021 | 0
3      | 01-02-2021 | 1
3      | 01-06-2021 | 0
3      | 01-09-2021 | 1
```

I'd like to add a fourth column that has, for each row, the most recent date *prior to the date in that row* that the Person was In-office:

```
Person | Date       | In-office | Most recent in-office 
-------------------------------------------------------
1      | 01-01-2021 | 0         | Null
1      | 01-02-2021 | 1         | Null
1      | 01-04-2021 | 0         | 01-02-2021
1      | 01-08-2021 | 1         | 01-02-2021
2      | 01-02-2021 | 1         | Null
2      | 01-05-2021 | 0         | 01-02-2021
2      | 01-09-2021 | 0         | 01-02-2021
3      | 01-01-2021 | 0         | Null
3      | 01-02-2021 | 1         | Null
3      | 01-06-2021 | 1         | 01-02-2021
3      | 01-09-2021 | 1         | 01-06-2021
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this in Hive? I haven't been able to figure out a way to do this using window functions / partitioning. In principle joining the table to itself on `person` and applying some sensible filters and aggregations should work, but my actual data is on the order of tens of millions of rows and in practice this has not been feasible given my resource constraints.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the `MAX` window function and limiting the bounds to preceding rows with (`RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` ). By filtering dates based on whether the person was in office in the case expression (`CASE WHEN in_office=1 THEN cdate END`) and using the order (`ORDER BY date` ) and range of the over clause, we can retrieve the most in office date of that person eg

```sql
select
   *,
   MAX(CASE WHEN in_office=1 THEN date END) OVER (
       PARTITION BY person 
       ORDER BY date 
       RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING 
   ) as most_recent_in_office
from sample_data
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I hadn't thought of using CASE WHEN inside of the MAX window function. I'll give this a try and report back if it works :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- this appears to have worked for my use case!

Comment: @user3447259 Great. Please upvote and then mark as the accepted answer so that other stackoverflow visitors with similar questions will be able to identify that the answer may be used to solve their question/problem.